# How to write customer equalsTo/compareTo/hasCode for TreeMap to get Top N values

Tags: java, sorting, treemap

The question is:
Clients want to see which items are most sold so far. We want to provide this data to our clients efficiently.
Sample input:
List of sold items:
F|400 
      B|1000
A|500
A|600
C|1000
D|700
E|300
Sample output
A|1100
       C|1000
B|1000
D|700

My thought is in first API `processInput()`, use a map of item and value to track all items sold so far and then add the updated item into a max priority queue. And in second API `processQuery()`, just select top K from queue. One issue is in `processQuery`, time complexity is `O(NlogN)`.
 Is it possible we solve this problem with a single `TreeMap` by overriding `equalsTo`, '`compareTo`, and `hasCode` so that that treemap is sorted by value. So we just iterate over the  TreeMap and return topN items?

Comment: Hi! `TreeMap` sorts by key, not by value. Also, please describe your problem better. What is `processInput()`? What is `processQuery`? The methods are called `hashCode`, `equals` and `compareTo`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If your highest priority is the _most efficient_ solution, you'd probably need something like Guava's [`Comparators.greatest`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html#greatest-int-java.util.Comparator-).  It's third-party, but it's more efficient than either a `TreeMap`-based approach or a `PriorityQueue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need efficient access in both directions: when items come, you need to get the aggregated amount based on their name (A,B,C), but for sorting them, the aggregated amount is going to be used. I think you could use a `Map` for finding items by name, and a `SortedSet` for sorting. As amounts themselves are not unique (like B and C have both 1000 in the example), sorting should also make use of the name (as those are unique), and that's why a set is enough for that part:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Test {
    static class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
        final String name;
        int amount;
        Item(String name,int amount){
            this.name=name;
            this.amount=amount;
        }
        public int compareTo(Item o) {
            if(o.amount<amount)
                return -1;
            if(o.amount>amount)
                return 1;
            return o.name.compareTo(name);
        }
        public String toString() {
            return name+"|"+amount;
        }
    }
    
    Map<String,Item> itemmap=new HashMap<>();
    SortedSet<Item> sorted=new TreeSet<>();
    
    void add(String name,int amount) {
        Item i=itemmap.get(name);
        if(i!=null) {
            sorted.remove(i);
            i.amount+=amount;
        } else {
            i=new Item(name,amount);
        }
        itemmap.put(name,i);
        sorted.add(i);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t=new Test();
        t.add("F",400);
        t.add("B",1000);
        t.add("xA",500);
        t.add("xA",600);
        t.add("C",1000);
        t.add("D",700);
        t.add("E",300);
        System.out.println("itemmap: "+t.itemmap);
        System.out.println("sorted: "+t.sorted);
    }
}
```

It produces the output (test on Ideone: https://ideone.com/2d79aC)

> ```
> itemmap: {B=B|1000, C=C|1000, D=D|700, E=E|300, F=F|400, xA=xA|1100}
> sorted: [xA|1100, C|1000, B|1000, D|700, F|400, E|300]
> ```

I deliberately renamed `A` to `xA`, otherwise the map would be `A|1100, B|1000, C|1000`, but that's just a coincidence of alphabetical order (hashing a few consecutive, single-letter strings does not really mix the order). C and B come in this reverse order because that's what you have asked for. If you want them as B, then C, swap the `compareTo()`, or just return the current one with a negative sign.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input is a list of strings in the mentioned format, the first step `processInput` is to convert the input list into list of some objects {name, num}:

```java
public static List<Obj> processInput(List<String> data) {
    return Arrays.stream(data)
                 .map(s -> s.split("\\|"))
                 .map(arr -> new Obj(arr[0], Integer.parseInt(arr[1])))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then the second method groups by the name, sums up the total value, and returns similar list as a result:

```java
public static List<Obj> getTopTotals(List<Obj> data, int topCount) {
    return data.stream()
               .collect(
                       Collectors.groupingBy(Obj::getName, TreeMap::new,
                       Collectors.summingInt(Obj::getNum)
                )) // get TreeMap<String, Integer> of totals
                .entrySet().stream()
                .sorted((a, b) -> b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue())) // sort by value desc
                .limit(topCount)
                .map(e -> new Obj(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```